# What is Return type of method invocation?

Tags: java, distributed, distributed-transactions, proxy-classes

I am using Proxy Pattern in Java (`InvocationHandler`), to implement a lock manager for a remote object, in the proxy class (which implements `InvocationHandler`). I am calling the remote object (here : `flighRMConnection`) :

```
if (method.getName().toLowerCase().contains("query")){
    lm.Lock(Thread.currentThread(), READ);
} else {
    lm.Lock(Thread.currentThread(), WRITE)
}               
method.invoke(flightRMConnection, args);
```

How can I check the value returned by the invocation?(there might be different types of results)

Thanks , Arian

Comment: You should assign `READ` or `WRITE` to a variable depending on the conditional `method.getName().toLowerCase().contains("query")`, then call `lm.Lock` with it to avoid repeating yourself. You could also use a ternary inline. It would make the question more readable anyway.

Comment: I know , but there are several threads accessing this object and I am afraid to have a local variable for sake of safety.besides it's not related to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the static return type of [`invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is naturally `Object`. If you want to determine the dynamic type of an instance returned by the invocation, you can call [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) on it to get the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object representing its type.

If you need to inspect its contents, you can do further reflection using the `Class` (see [`getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29), etc.). If there's a known class or interface the object might extend, you could also check that with `instanceof` and then cast it.

Oh and don't forget to make sure the returned object isn't `null` before you call anything on it.

Comment: actually there are several thread accessing this proxy class, if I put the returned object in a variable and then do the checking afterwards, could this variable be changed by other threads ?

Comment: That depends on what kind of variable. If you want a special variable for each thread, consider using [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Comment: I mean if I put the returned object of the invocation in an object 'Obj' , could this 'Obj' be altered by other threads before checking it ?

Comment: Yes, if you assigned the object to a field, another thread could reassign it (and it's visibility wouldn't be deterministic unless it was `volatile`). But I don't see why you wouldn't just inspect the object after getting it back, before releasing the lock.

Comment: because there could be multiple SHARED locks , which means that several threads may pass the locking at the same time not being stuck there  , and they would have their own results and I am afraid that they write the result others' results, I don't know what to do ! besides I don't want to use `synchronized`

Comment: Did you read about `ThreadLocal`? That's my only remaining suggestion.